# How to copy data from C++ array to Eigen matrix or vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, eigen

I have some data in a C++ array, `double myData[10]`; I want to copy `n` elements of this array to a vector in Eigen, declared as `Eigen::MatrixXd myVector`. I could do them one at a time in a loop, but there must be a way to copy the entire array. I tried this code, but it gets a compile error (error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value):

```
myVector.resize(4); myVector.data() = myData;
```

I do NOT want to map the array, as the C++ array will go out of scope, and the amount of extra memory to copy is trivial.

What is the appropriate method for copying from the C++ array to the Eigen vector? From a 2-D C++ array to an Eigen matrix?

Comment: post the FULL compiler error, cmon man!

Comment: I added the error message.

Comment: You could do the mapping followed by copying. It is more elegant than using two loops and element-wise assignments

Comment: What do you mean by '2-D C++ array'?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the existing data with an Eigen object (`Map`) and then copy it to your object:

```
myVector = Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>(myData, rows, cols);
```

Comment: The mapping is a reference, but the assignment afterwards issues a copy operation

Comment: Whether this works, depends on the memory-layout of `myData` of course. (The question did not specify what was meant by "2D C++ array", though).

Comment: "2D C++ array" is, for example, `double my2DArray[5][10]`.

Comment: What @chtz meant, and s/he's right, is that the storage order was not specified in the question. The answer assumes column major storage order.

Comment: The storage order in the C++ 2-D array is last subscript varies most rapidly, so the elements are stored in order of increasing columns. For example, a_00, a_01, a_02; a_10, a_11, a_12; a_20, a_21, a_22 is the storage order for `double a[3][3]`.

Comment: Note that the `rows` and `cols` can be omitted when using a fixed-size matrix (e.g. `Map<Vector3d>(myData)` works).